# In a Stack Overflow job listing, the “Express interest” and “★ Save” buttons' text are vertically misaligned

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

"Save" isn't vertically centered.
[image]

Comment: I don't see any issue here

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson Really? The "Save" text is clearly not aligned with the other button text or the star icon.

Comment: @Turnip Sorry, I got it now.

Comment: It appears that the word "Save" is bottom-aligned with the star, but because it's smaller, it's not top-aligned.  Perhaps all words and the star in all buttons in that row should be the same height _and_ they should be all vertically aligned (not the "...", which can't be the same height, but still should be vertically centered).

Comment: I've removed the status-review tag from this post, since the Jobs feature no longer exists.